# How to run python script from coldfusion10?

Tags: python, coldfusion

I found similar questions on python and Java but I can't solve my problem effectively.

I have a python script that carries intellectual property protection. So I cant rewrite it in Java. Now I need to run this python script which contacts the Postgresql 9.1 database and returns processed information as result. This python script gets updated every 3 months.

Now I need to run this from Coldfusion 10 application without affecting the performance of the application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to read this article, [Running Python on ColdFusion](http://www.compoundtheory.com/?action=displayPost&ID=118)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where does the python script reside? If its on the same machine as CF, you can use [CFEXECUTE](http://cfdocs.org/cfexecute) to execute the python script.

Comment: I tried 
<cfexecute 
name = "E:\Garagespace\python\helloworld\src\printhello.py" 
outputFile = "C:\Temp\outputpython.txt" 
timeout = "10"> 
</cfexecute>

but got error
The cause of this exception was that: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "E:/Garagespace/python/helloworld/src/printhello.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: @NaranRaj you most likely need to use cfexecute to execute the python.exe and then pass the script to execute in as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

CFGroovy seems to be able to run Python

http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/projects/cfgroovy2/